# How to find the longest element in a double coset of a Weyl group using SageMath?

Tags: group-theory, math-software, sagemath, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

I asked a question about computing longest element in a double coset in [AskSage](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/59591/how-to-find-the-element-with-maximal-length-in-a-double-coset-of-a-coxeter-group/)

It has not been answered for a long time. So I asked it here.

Let $W$ be a finite Coxeter group. Denote by $W_I$ the subgroup of $W$ generated by $s_i$, $i \in I$, $I$ is a subset of the set of vertices of the Dynkin diagram of $W$. For any $w \in W$, and $I, J$ subsets of the set of vertices of the Dynkin diagram, I would like to write a function in Sagemath to find the element of maximal length in the double coset $W_I w W_J$. In type A, the case of symmetric group, I wrote the following program and it works.

```
def LongestPermInDoubleCoset(S1,w,S2): # longest element in S1 w S2, S1,S2 are subgroups of S_n

    winner = W.identity()
    for u1 in S1:
        for u2 in S2:
            t1=u1*w*u2
            if t1.length()>winner.length():
            winner=t1
    r=winner

return r

W=SymmetricGroup(6)
[s1,s2,s3,s4,s5] = W.simple_reflections()
S1=[W.identity(), s1]
S2=[W.identity(),s2]
t1=LongestPermInDoubleCoset(S1,s1,S2)
t2=t1.reduced_word()
t2
```

One problem in the above program is that I have to give S1, S2 explicitly. I would like to revise the program such that when given S1, S2, I only need to give simple reflections. For example, when give S1=[W.identity(), s1], I would like to give $S1 = <\text{generated by s1}>$.

Another problem in the above program is that it works only for symmetric group. How to revise it such that it works for any Coxeter group (or at least Weyl group)? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your question purely about syntax -- you give subgroups, but still run through all elements of the double coset? Or are you asking for a more clever algorithm that finds the smallest element only from generators of the subgroups (without writing out all subgroup elements)?

Comment: @ahulpke, thank you very much for your comments. Yes, I am asking for a more clever algorithm that finds the smallest element only from generators of the subgroups (without writing out all subgroup elements). I tried the following 
    def LongestPermInDoubleCosetWeylGroup(W,S1,w,S2):  
        g1=W.subgroup(S1)
        g2=W.subgroup(S2)
        winner = W.one()
        for u1 in g1:
            for u2 in g2:
                t1=u1*w*u2
                if t1.length()>winner.length():
                    winner=t1
        r=winner
    
        return r

Comment: But when I run: typ='A'
rank=4
W=WeylGroup(typ+str(rank), prefix = 's')
s = W.simple_reflections()
LongestPermInDoubleCosetWeylGroup(W,[s1,s2],s1*s3,[s2])

It is said that TypeError: object of type 'sage.matrix.matrix_rational_dense.Matrix_rational_dense' has no len()

Comment: @ahulpke, I figured out that the problem is that I need to use s[1] instead of s1. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following codes work.

```
def LongestPermInDoubleCosetWeylGroupGivenTypeRank(S1,w,S2,typ,rank): # typ='A', longest element in S1 w S2, S1,S2 are generating sets
    W=WeylGroup(typ+str(rank), prefix = 's')
    g1=W.subgroup(S1)
    g2=W.subgroup(S2)
    winner = W.one()
    for u1 in g1:
        for u2 in g2:
            t1=u1*w*u2
            if t1.length()>winner.length():
                winner=t1
    r=winner

    return r

typ='A'
rank=4
W=WeylGroup(typ+str(rank), prefix = 's')
s = W.simple_reflections()
t2=LongestPermInDoubleCosetWeylGroupGivenTypeRank([s[1],s[2]],s[1]*s[3],[s[2]], typ, rank)
t2
```